# code inside onclick event not working in next js even after using "use client" directive

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am new to next js just started with basic but event after using using "use client" directive which enables client side rendering my code indside onclick button does not work pls suggest a solution?

```
"use client"
import { useState } from 'react'
    
    export default function Login(){
        const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
        return(
       <div>
        <h1>login</h1>
        <button type='button'  onClick={()=>alert("hii")}>hii</button>
        <div>
          <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
          <button type='button' onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
        </div>
       </div>
        )
    }
```

this is my folder structure

[image: this is my folder structure]

Comment: I just copy and paste your code and works